# How to use inject fake timers to simulate fake dates and times IN browser using WebdriverIO and SinonJS or lolex

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, sinon, webdriver-io

I'm doing JavaScript E2E test with webdriverIO, and I want to simulate mock dates and times so that certain scenarios that are time sensitive can be ran correctly.

I.E.) Certain elements should not appear on the application's page after a certain time OR certain elements should be available after or before a certain time.

I have tried to do something like this in my wdio.conf.js "before" hook:

```
let lolex = require('lolex');
try {
    browser.execute(function(lolex) {
    const clock = lolex.createClock(new Date(2020, 10, 14, 10, 10));
        window.Date = clock.Date;
    },lolex);
}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

I expected this to work, I was following this stackoverflow post: [How to use Fake timers with nightwatch.js and sinon.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36232948/how-to-use-fake-timers-with-nightwatch-js-and-sinon-js) for guidance where they are using nightwatch.js instead, but for some reason I was still not able to figure it out.

The error I am getting is this "javascript error: lolex.createClock is not a function", it seems like that lolex is not being imported correctly.

Comment: Hi Friend, I guess the error is thrown because the real browser does know what is `lolex`. Because the real browser does not have that object(as like window or document which exist by default). So i guess you might need to try injecting the lolex module in the real browser before using it. I have not personally tried it. But i will try some researching too.

Comment: @NaveenThiyagarajan, how would I be able to inject lolex into the actual browser itself?